# Error: [screen is terminating] after quit screen

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-ec2, gnu-screen

I started a screen session with `screen python3 file_name.py`

I put that screen in the background with "ctrl-A" and then "d".

I quit the screen with `screen -X -S [session # you want to kill] quit`

I now want to re-run: `screen python3 file_name.py`

I'm getting the error: `[screen is terminating]`

Any help is appreciated. I read over `man screen` but was still unable to figure out a fix. If it's significant I'm running these commands on an amazon EC2 instance.

Answer (score 0):

To execute script directly, use:

```
$ screen ./file_name.py
```

If you open session like this:

```
$ screen file_name.py
```

Command is without relative or absolute path and screen looks for `file_name.py` within  $PATH folders.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add the python3 to the screen command when copying to stack overflow. I believe I am executing the scripts directly with "screen python3 file_name.py"

Comment: Are you sure? Then it will be about your script. Can you post it?

Comment: ssh'd back into the server today, and it was working again. I didn't even do anything so not sure what the bug was :/